# Could not create Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic / Could not find a part of the path

Tags: vb.net, logging, location, console-application, .net-4.7.2

This one has me stumped.

I'm working in visual studio 2015. Having issues with a legacy console application.

This application normally writes logs under C:\AppName\Ftp\Log\ (or D on the server).

But suddenly, it seems the FileLogTraceListener tries to validate a path under the UserName folder before even checking for custom settings.

So ALL code using My.Application.Log crashes with the title error and the InnerException:

*{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Go / Gd\AppName.exe\8.1.0.0'.."}*

and the InnerExeption Stack Trace:
*at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.IO.Directory.Internal…*

Here's the bit of code I'm currently trying to run.

```
My.Application.Log.DefaultFileLogWriter.Location = Logging.LogFileLocation.Custom
```

The app.config contains:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
          <listeners>
              <add name="FileLog"/>
          </listeners>
      </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" 
      type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, 
      Microsoft.VisualBasic, 
      Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, 
      processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
      initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I've tried adding location information directly in the listener to no avail.

This started after upgrading the .Net framework from .Net 4.5.2 to .Net 4.7.2. (This solution has projects in common with another solution that's needs the upgrade), I suspect this is an issue/corruption with this project because other console apps on my machine have no problems logging to the same folder with this FW.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone else will have the perfect trifecta required to produce this error, but just in case, here goes:

1. Have a bilingual "Company" in your Assembly (ex: Name / Nom).
   Specifically, a space followed by a front slash.
2. In the debugging tab, uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting
   process"
3. Upgrade the .Net framework to 4.7.2

We had the first 2 settings in our system for years and never had this problem, for some reason, upgrading the .Net framework causes it to crash.